# Python pickle converts to unicode between versions

Tags: python, unicode, pickle

I have a process that pickles a dictionary using Python 3.2.  I then need to unpickle this dictionary using Python 2.7 or 2.6.  The problem is that when transferring between python versions I get a dictionary full of unicode data which upsets the Python API I am trying to feed it into.

Pickling in Python 3.2:

```
myDict = {'a': 'first', 'b': 'second', 'c': 'third'}
with open(file, 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(myDict, f, 2)
```

Unpickling in Python 2.6:

```
with open(file, f) as f:
    myDict = pickle.load(f)
```

returns: {u'a': u'first', u'c': u'third', u'b': u'second'}

How can I get back exactly what I put in (i.e. not unicode)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're actually getting back exactly what you put in, since strings in [Python 3 *are* unicode](http://docs.python.org/release/3.0.1/whatsnew/3.0.html#text-vs-data-instead-of-unicode-vs-8-bit)

To get `str`'s, you can convert the keys and values in the dictionary:

```
strDict = dict((k.encode(), v.encode()) for k, v in myDict.iteritems())
```

Comment: Ah! my misunderstanding.  I hadn't realised that all strings in 3.x were unicode.  According to the pre v3 documentation, protocol = 0 is supposed to be an ASCII format, but you can't even use this to coerce the output to ASCII because something has been changed and the documentation for v3 is subtly altered from 'ASCII' to 'human readable' (sigh).  Your solution is quick and painless though.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As steef notes, you're getting back exactly what you put in, as in python 3 `'foo'` is a unicode string, and (in both versions) `b'foo'` is a byte string.

The solution after unpickling is to `encode` your strings to a byte representation.

An alternative would be to just serialise your data as, say, yaml, in whatever encoding you like.